# Create menu for add-on button

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I am a newbie in Firefox extension development and I intend to start creating an add-on using the beta version of the add-on builder. So far using the getting started tutorial I managed to create a button on the add-on bar, that when clicked opens a new tab. The code is below:

```
require("widget").Widget({

id: "widgetID1",
label: "Get Involved",
contentURL: "http://site.com/image.png",
onClick: function(event) {
require("tabs").open("http://www.mozilla.org");
}
});
```

I would like to know how to create a menu for the extension, so when the button is clicked a menu appears. Perhaps some guidance towards some documentation on this matter would be most useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [firefox extension menu](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6641808/firefox-extension-menu)

Answer (score 1):

You can associate a panel to a widget, and put a `<ul>` or `<ol>` in the panel.

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.0/packages/addon-kit/docs/panel.html
http://blog.mozilla.com/addons/2011/08/11/add-on-sdk-faq-widgets-panels/